# Django multi level reverse lookup

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I have a site where the items are classified by categories and subcategories. My models look like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('Subcategory')
```

I need to display all the items of one category and all the subcategories with the items in the same page (it's a requisite of the project) and the lists should be in order, like this:

Category:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4
- Item 5
- Item 6

Subcategory 1

- Item 1
- Item 3
- Item 4

Subcategory 2

- Item 2
- Item 5
- Item 6

So far I have two possible queries but I can't get this done.

```
items = Item.objects.prefetch_related('subcategory', 'subcategory__category').filter(subcategory__category__slug=categorySlug)
```

This query gives me a QuerySet and I can do a for loop in my template to show all the items but I can't order them by subcategory.

```
{% for item in items %}
```

What I need is something like *for subcategory in items.subcategory*.

The next query is the inverse:

```
category = Category.objects.prefetch_related('subcategory_set', 'subcategory_set__item_set').get(slug=categorySlug)
```

With this query I can do a loop to show the items by subcategory

```
{% for subcategory in category.subcategory_set.all %}
    {% for item in subcategory.item_set.all %}
```

What I can't do is to display all the items in order by category. I need something like *for item in category.subcategory_set__item_set.all* or *for item in category.subcategory_set.all.item_set.all*

I am aware that I can do it using multiple queries (in fact using the two queries at the same time), but I'm trying to use a single query to do this job. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can just take a list of subcategories and use [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

```
{% regroup subcategories by category as subcat_list %}

<ul>
{% for sub_cat in subcat_list %}
    <li>{{ sub_cat.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in sub_cat.list %}
          <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Can you do it with a single query? Not really since you need one to iterate over all subcategories and then another to for the categories to produce the first part of your list